# I have exported table data into excel and given a download option but i want to save the excel file in a folder using php

Tags: php, html, file, web-development-server

In the code below I am importing a form data of HTML table from another PHP file. Then, I exported the data to a csv file but it comes only when I download it. I want the exported excel sheet to store in a particular folder on my computer. Please help me on how to do it.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['export_excel']))
    {
        $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","online hra claim system");
        header("content-type:text/csv;charset=utf-8");
        header("content-Disposition:attachment; filename=download.csv");
        $output=fopen("php://output","w");
        fputcsv($output, array('CPF.NO','EMPLOYEE NAME','APPLICATION_ID','REMARKS','TIME_STAMP','CURRENT USER','CURRENT STATUS','PROOF FILE NAME'));
        $query="select * from hra_claim_workflow where current_status='A' and cur_user='T' order by time_stamp";
        $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            fputcsv($output, $row);
        }           
        fclose($output);

    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have used the below code
--------   $output=fopen("php://output","w");
which means you are saving it in the folder named "output"

you can use your specific path to save file
for example
--------   $output=fopen("php://specific/path/to/save/file","w");

this code will save the file inside "specific/path/to/save/file" directory

Comment: _“which means you are saving it in the folder named "output"”_ - no it doesn’t, it means that this is written directly to the output buffer. https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: And trying to use `php://specific/path/to/save/file` as a file system path, is also wrong. The `php://` prefix makes no sense there.